# $(this).val() returning incorrect value IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a trivia page that is dynamically generated by some javascript code. It works fine in most browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, IE9) but is having an odd issue with IE8. When I'm calling $(this).val() as part of a button click event handler, I'm getting an empty string as the response, even though the button clicked has a value.

**Relevant JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
        if(panel % numPanels === 1)
            {category = $(this).val();}
        nextPanel(prop);
    });
});
```

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div id="buttons">
<button type="button" class="btn" value="One">Group One</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" value="Two">Group Two</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" value="Three">Group Three</button>
</div>
```

Any idea what's up?

Edit: I'm using jQuery 1.7.2, and using `console.log($(this).attr("value"))` and `console.log($(this).prop("value"))` are also returning a blank string.

Comment: Are you using ready handler ?

Comment: There's some other stuff there that might be the problem. How did you verify that it's `.val()` that returns the empty string?

Comment: Yes, it's under the ready handler. As for the .val() I checked the value of category using breakpoints directly before and after the assignment, and it changed from undefined to "".

Comment: What happens if you do a `console.log($(this).attr("value"))`, within you click handler?

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: With console.log($(this).attr("value")) I'm still getting an empty string. I'm using jQuery 1.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a bug in <button> if you are going to use javascript then my surgestion is that you use the html -data attribute:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-value="One">Group One</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-value="Two">Group Two</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-value="Three">Group Three</button>
</div>
```

and use the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
        if(panel % numPanels === 1) {
            category = $(this).data("value");
        }
        nextPanel(prop);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$(this).attr("value")`

or

you can use `$(this).prop("value")`

jQuery 1.6+ version needed for .prop()

Answer (score 0):

Try to fecth the value using `.attr`

**EDIT : adding complete code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
     if(panel % numPanels === 1)
// retrieve using attr
         {category = $(this).attr("value");}
     nextPanel(prop);
 }); 
});
```